# Hibernate - unique column constraint being ignored

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a MySQL table to hold tags (i.e. like those used here on Stack Overflow). It simply has an id (pk) and a tag column to hold the tag itself.

The annotated get methods for my Tag entity are shown below.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

@Column(name = "tag", unique = true, nullable = false)
public String getTag() {
    return this.tag;
}
```

I am using a unique column constraint on tag as there should never be more than one row for a given tag.  However, Hibernate appears to be ignoring this, i.e. I can save the exact same tag many times and it simply creates a new row rather than throwing an exception.

Am I missing something or should this be working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From JavaDoc of [`UniqueConstraint`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html) (`unique=true` on `@Colunm` is just a shortcut):

> This annotation is used to specify that a unique constraint is to be included in the generated DDL for a primary or secondary table.

So it does not seem to enforce uniqueness upon inserts. You should create a unique constraint in the database in any case.

Answer (score 1):

You miss that this is only a information.

You should add also constraint on the column in database.

Comment: These annotations are not purely informational. What I have found (in current versions of hibernate) is that the hbm2ddl update process does not add new constraints, but if the constraint exists on the class when the table is first created, it (hbm2ddl) will create the constraint (for postgres 9.3, probably others)