# Hibernate unique annotation does not work

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Good day!
I try to do entities with unique ID and unique NAME.
So,

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntityImpl implements Serializable, BaseEntity
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  protected Long id;

  @Column(unique = true)
  protected String name;
//here are getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class SimpleEntity extends BaseEntityImpl
{ 
}
```

Here is my DAO

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public class SimpleDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements SimpleDao
{
   public SimpleEntity createOrUpdate(SimpleEntity entity)
   {
       getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
       return entity;
   }
}
```

And here is my unit test (using in memory derby db)

```
@Test
public void create()
{
    SimpleEntity entity = new SimpleEntity();
    entity.setName("name1");

    SimpleEntity entity2 = new SimpleEntity();
    entity2.setName("name1");

    simpleDao.createOrUpdate(entity);
    simpleDao.createOrUpdate(entity2);
}
```

I expect that this test will throw an exception, because I try to save two entities with the same name, but it works fine!

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Was the attribute set when you created the database?

Comment: Sorry, what attribute are you talking about?

Comment: The `unique` attribute is only used for schema generation and won't enforce uniqueness on inserts/updates by itself. If you let hibernate generate your schema, then you _should_ get a unique constraint on `name` at the database level which will cause an exception. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105164/hibernate-unique-column-constraint-being-ignored

Comment: Thanks, it is a key for me.  But I use in memory derby db when unit-tests, so it is created before tests. And it looks like this annotation are ignored. I also tried add  @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"NAME"}) at @Table annotation but have no result...

Comment: So, it is likely that it is derby ignores Unique Constraint. In MySql DB all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

So, it is likely that it is derby ignores Unique Constraint. In MySql DB all works fine