# Spring Boot Unit Test Unique Constraint ignored

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

I'm experiencing a different behaviour of my application REST controller between unit testing and running it normally. I have added a @Column(unique = true) on one of my fields to constrain a unique number, somehow it's being ignored in the unit test and I cannot understand why. I'm showing an abbreviated example below, basically adding a vehicle with same number twice to a shop:

```
@Test
    public void CreateVehicle_SameNR_NOK() {
        Shop shop = shopController.createVehicle(0L,1,new Vehicle("AAA",
                "111222"));
        Assert.assertEquals(shop.getVehicles().size(),1);

        shopController.createVehicle(0L,1,new Vehicle("AAA",
                "111222"));

        Assert.assertEquals(shop.getVehicles().size(),1); //This fails.
    }


@Entity
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true) //ignored in unit test?
    private String nr;


    protected Vehicle() {}

    public Vehicle(String name, String nr) {
        this.name = name;       
        this.nr = nr;        
    }   

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   

    public String getNr() {
        return nr;
    }

    public void setNr(String nr) {
        this.nr = nr;
    }  
}
```

## application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test_mem;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
debug=true
```

## ShopController extract

```
@RequestMapping(value ="{id}/shop/{shopId}/vehicle", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Shop createShopVehicle(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable Long shopId, @RequestBody Vehicle vehicle) {
        Shop shop = shopRepository.findOne(shopId);
        shop.getVehicles().add(vehicle);
        shopRepository.save(shop);
        return shop;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the same database in both cases? Or are you running with for example MySQL when running normally and H2 or HSQLDB in the tests?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105164/hibernate-unique-column-constraint-being-ignored

Comment: in my application.properties I have only H2 mem configured as this is a light-weight project where I'm experimenting. Therefore it should be same database.

Comment: @HajderRabiee It would be useful to see your `ShopController` class and the `application.properties`.

Comment: Have you tried flushing?
Unique constraints get triggered in the database, not as JSR 303 bean validations.
You need to get the INSERT statement to ram against the database to get an explosion.
You have three alternatives:
(a) flush.
(b) try to commit the transaction
(c) invoke a read all query

Either of these three should fire a flush,
And if your Alter table statement was triggered, during schema creation to add the unique constraint, you will get your error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue in Spring Boot using JPA and Postgres.

Once I changed my statements from:

```
repository.save(entity)
```

to:

```
repository.saveAndFlush(entity)
```

it started throwing a DataIntegrityViolationException in the tests due to a violated unique constraint.

Since you're doing code-first I'll assume you're having it create the tables automatically for you. Verify in the created schema that the unique constraint is there after auto-creation of your tables.

Also for your code I'd recommend catching and re-throwing a 409 conflict.. ex:

```
try {
    shopRepository.saveAndFlush(shop)
} catch (div: DataIntegrityViolationException) {
    throw ResponseStatusException(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.CONFLICT, "already exists")
}
```